# How to automatically rebuild linked projects in Netbeans?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I have two maven projects in Netbeans.

First project - maven project of the Java library.

Second project - maven project of the web app.

First project - in the dependecies of the second project, ie second project is depend by first project.

Is it posissible automatically redeploy second project (web app), what running on the Tomcat, when I change code of the second project (maven project of the Java library)?

Now, when I change code of the maven project of the Java library, I need manually Clean And Build it and than re-deploy second project. It gives a great inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is an Enterprise Application. Check this example: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-entapp.html